# cannot load such file -- dbd-pg (LoadError) when executing tests

Tags: ruby

I am trying to execute my tests but it is complaining about the dbd/pg gem.

The error code is not liking the require statement for dbd/pg.

in code files I have:

```
require 'pg'
require 'dbd-pg'
require 'dbi'
```

Gemfiles:

```
gem 'dbi'
gem 'pg'
gem 'dbd-pg'
```

I have changed the gem reference to dbd/pg and dbd-pg.
I have tried specific gem installs of pg and dbd/pg in my

Comment: What exactly have you tried?  What were the specific results of your attempts?

Comment: I'd suggest including some code so we know what you're trying to do.

Comment: Did it install correctly? Are you sure you need it? IIRC that gem is like a decade old.

Comment: yes the gems installed fine. We do need this for pg connections unless a better method or gem has come about recently.